# Files don't inherit parent folder's permission after saving

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2008, file-permissions

We have a Windows 2008 R2 File Server. On the D: partition we have a couple of folders with permissions for each department. Somehow if a user moves e.g. an excel file into an other folder the file doesn't inherit the parent folders permission. Meaning finally the owner of the file is the only one able to access it even though multiple user have full access for the folder.

How can this happend? How can I make sure that all files inherit the parent folder's permission?

Furthermore I read the following statement, I'm not sure if it's completely true:

> If you think about it,  it all makes perfect sense.  When you move a
>   file to a different partition, it  actually copies the whole file
>   over, then deletes it from the index table on  the source partition. 
>   When you move it on the same partition, it just has to  re-index it. 
>   The file itself is not moved.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is the folder actually set to inherit permissions from the parent? Are the security settings on that folder set to affect only that folder, or that folder plus all sub folders/files?

Comment: the folder is set to inherit the permissions from the parents as well as to inherit it's permissions to all subfolders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The security settings are right. The problem is Microsofts behaviour (or the one of the user):

If I move a file from the same partition to an other folder the security settings are not adapted even though the security settings are set correctly (inheriting permissions). Meaning to solve the problem I copy the file I want to move into the new folder to my Desktop (other partition) first and than movie it to the destination folder. Like this the files permission get overwritten/inherited form the parent folder.

Meaning the following is true:

```
   When you move a file to a different partition, it actually copies the whole file over, then deletes it from the index table on the source partition. When you move it on the same partition, it just has to re-index it. The file itself is not moved.
```

Comment: How does that account for when saving from Excel?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question, what do you mean?

Comment: From your original question: "Somehow if a user saves e.g. an Excel file with "Save as..." the file doesn't inherit the parent folders permission", that's a creation of a file, not a copy or a move. Your original question doesn't actually mention copying for moving files, just saving from Excel.  So how does your answer solve the problem when saving from Excel?

Comment: That was actually a missunderstanding between the user having the problem and me. I'll try to correct it, thanks for the input.